# proxy server stops after starting the service

Tags: java, bash, azure-devops, proxy, azure-pipelines

I am running java jar in azure pipeline like below in bash task

```
nohup java -jar pit-bastion-tunnel-$(ver).jar &
```

The proxy server started and stopped like below

```
[main] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer - Proxy started at address: /127.0.0.1:11111
[main] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer - Shutting down proxy server gracefully
[main] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer - Closing all channels (graceful)
[main] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ServerGroup - Shutting down server group event loops (graceful)
```

Does azure doesn't support the background run of the proxy server or am I missing any configuration?

Comment: A question: you're expecting all clients of that proxy to connect from the same host as that on which that proxy is (was) running?

Comment: @g00se Yes all clients of the proxy to connect to same host

Comment: I can't answer your question (for one thing I know nothing of Azure), but I can make an 'improving suggestion': try using ```tmux```, which is *tons* better than ```nohup``` . If it doesn't solve the problem, you'll still be better off.